# Iron:Router not work after using vsivsi:file-collection for storing tempoary files

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm doing an app that use netanelgilad:excel to export json to excel files.

I follow its example (http://meteorpad.com/pad/2hjNqmwHjDvkxvLC5/Leaderboard) and use vsivsi:file-collection to store temporary files. Plus, I'm using irou:router for my other routes.

The app works fine on my local machine but iron:router does not work on the production server. Below is the code that relates to vsivsi:file-collection and its routing. Does it conflict with Iron:Router? If so, why the app works fine locally?

```
temporaryFiles = new FileCollection('temporaryFiles', {
  resumable: false,   // Enable built-in resumable.js upload support
  http: [
    {
      method: 'get',
      path: '/:_id',  // this will be at route "/gridfs/temporaryFiles/:_id"
      lookup: function (params) {  // uses express style url params
        return { _id: params._id};       // a query mapping url to myFiles
      }
    },
    {
      method: 'post',
      path: '/:_id',
      lookup: function (params) {
        return {
          _id: params._id
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});

temporaryFiles.allow({
  insert: function (userId, file) {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, file) {
    return true;
  },
  read: function (userId, file) {
    return true;
  },
  write: function (userId, file, fields) {
    return true;
  }
});
```